# Outlook email ripping application to start upon receiving mail?

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, attachment

I want to start an application whenever an email arrives in outlook. Is there anyway I could achive this? I have developed an application that rip attachments from an email(this being the app I want to execute), whereby a user will send an excel spreadsheet and this is ripped from the mailbox and imported into an Oracle database. Does anyone know how I could invoke the app to start as soon as an email arrives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use OpenPop http://hpop.sourceforge.net/ and do it in any background app or Create VSTO adding for outlook and hook newmail event